# angular js infinite scroll issue using ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i made page with infinite scroll page load more script i am using ionic angular js for my code issue is that when page reaches bottom it restart from begning

below is html code:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">

<ion-list>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items">
      Item : {{ item.username }}
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>
```

and js code

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
         $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;

          $scope.loadMore = function() {

            $http.get('http://serverurl/a.php?page='+$scope.items.length).success(function(items) { 
                //$scope.username = items;
                $scope.items = items;
                //$scope.items.push(items);
                console.log(items)
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
            });

          };

          $scope.items = [];
    });
```

pls check code on codepen : http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/dGZbZK?editors=101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is making just two requests page 0 or page 10. Because you are checking length.

Here is a slightly modified code which kind of works, but you should implement pagination in a little better way. This is just a working code to give you some idea:

Plunker link - http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/obovaP

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
$scope.currentPage = 0;

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    if($scope.currentPage == 3) {
       //no more items
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
       return;
    }

    $http.get('http://serverurl/a.php?page='+$scope.currentPage).success(function(items) { 
$scope.currentPage += 1;
        //$scope.username = items;
        $scope.items = $scope.items.concat(items);
        //$scope.items.push(items);
        console.log(items)
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });

  };
$scope.items = [];
});
```

Also note that since you have only 3 pages, you should add a check for that as well.

Comment: thanks i modified code based on your code see : http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/obovaP

instead of putting static count $scope.currentPage == 3)

can we put code so it stops when no output

Comment: Yes, but ideally, your service (API) should expose a service to get the total number of items. you can call such service first to get to know how many items are available. Else, you can check for the empty response and stop there. As I said, this code is just to give you an idea, you can make a cleaner implementation based on this.